# Suggested measure theory books for certain exercises

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

I was wondering if anyone knows books with difficult exercises of the theorems of monotone and dominated convergence and if the motto of Fatou possible.

I use Bartle but it does not have many exercises demonstrations.

Thank you very much.
regards

Comment: There is a solution manual to Bartle, maybe it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

The book by Réne Schilling, *Measures, Integrals and Martingales*, has a lot of exercises on this topic and there is a solution manual (with full solutions to all exercises) on the [web page](http://motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/index.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Real Analysis for Graduate Students by Richard Bass is available for free [online](http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real.html).

He's got about 26 problems just on MCT, DCT and Fatou, (Chapter 7, Page 56) but a lot of other problems throughout the book can be solved using these theorems.